# Angular route not showing view

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

I'm having an issue making route work:

```
angular_app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('Title', {
        controller : 'TitleController',
        templateUrl : 'app/html/Title.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : 'Title'
    });
});
```

This will not fire correctly, however if I edit like so:

```
angular_app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/', {
        controller : 'TitleController',
        templateUrl : 'app/html/Title.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : 'Title',
        controller : 'TitleController',
        templateUrl : 'app/html/Title.html'
    });
});
```

It does fire my controller, but it does it twice. Why does it not work on the first case?.

My app will have it's entry point on my Title.html file.

Any tips?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Need to read the documentation a little closer.

The first argument needs to be the path with a leading `/`. Also `redirectTo` should also be a path that is already declared in a `when()`

```
angular_app.config(function($routeProvider){
    $routeProvider.when('/title', {
        controller : 'TitleController',
        templateUrl : 'app/html/Title.html'
    }).otherwise({
        redirectTo : '/title'            
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your code to this.

```
angular_app.config(function($routeProvider){
$routeProvider.when('/title', {
    controller : 'TitleController',
    controllerAs: 'Title',
    templateUrl : 'app/html/Title.html'
}).otherwise({
    redirectTo : '/title'            
});});
```